# Swift 2 get the number of images in main bundle

Tags: ios, swift2

How do I convert this from obj-c to swift 2?

```
myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIImage *image;
    NSUInteger nimages = 0; 
    for (; ; nimages++)
    {
        NSString *nameOfImg_ = entity.attribute;
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name%@number%lu.jpg", nameOfImg_, (unsigned long)(nimages + 1)];
        image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageName ofType:nil]];
        if (image == nil) {
            break;
        }
        [myArray addObject:image];
    }
```

Comment: This isn't a free code translation service. Make an attempt. Update your question with your attempted Swift code. Explain what issues you are having.

Comment: @rmaddy nobody asked you to contribute. If you don't want to contribute keep it to yourself.

Comment: I'm telling you how this site works. That is a valid contribution.

Comment: @rmaddy that is "obstruction". but lets not argue about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**EDITED**

```
let myArray = NSMutableArray()
    var image:UIImage!
    var nimages = 0

    for(;;nimages++){

        let nameOfImg_ = entity.attribute
        let imageName = String(format: "name%@number%lu.jpg", arguments: [nameOfImg_,(nimages + 1)])
        if((NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(imageName, ofType: nil)) != nil){
            image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(imageName, ofType: nil)!)
            myArray.addObject(image!)

        }else{
            break
        }
    }
```

**entity.attribute** must be a String

Comment: I am going into eternal loop adding image for ever.... it seems that break doesn't do the work!

Comment: remove semicolon from break.well that doesn't make much. Also tell me what do u want to achieve.

Comment: same thing...endless loop... I have a finite number of images (varying from 1 to 10) and I want to add these to the myArray. if the image reaches last image then break... and stop

Comment: I suspect `image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(imageName, ofType: nil)!)` this line will crash the code

Comment: @GeorgeAsda change %s to %@ `name%@number%lu.jpg`. This is not the solution. Just a bug fix. I updated too

Comment: @GeorgeAsda Edited my answer. Check that it works. I guess it will and will break out

Comment: lol: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Where's the error coming in which line? Its working fine here.

Comment: as you said on the: image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(imageName, ofType: nil)!)

Comment: The newly edited code that I posted, is it coming for that also. Here it is not coming. Earlier it was coming before the edited code

Comment: It will first check whether this image exists in bundle or not by executing `if((NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(imageName, ofType: nil)) != nil)` . If it doesn't exists it will go to else block and break. How can it come in `image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(imageName, ofType: nil)!)`. Please recheck the code as I already made a sample for that which is working fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95860/discussion-between-george-asda-and-rajan-maheshwari).

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = [UIImage]()

var image : UIImage? = nil
var nimages = 0

while nimages != 0  && image == nil{
    let imageName = "name\(entity.attribute)number\(nimages+1)"
    image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(imageName, ofType: nil )!)
    nimages++
    if image != nil{
        myArray.append(image!)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = [UIImage]()
var image:UIImage?
var nimages: UInt = 0
for ; ; nimages++ {
    var nameOfImg_: String = entity.attribute
    var imageName: String = "name\(nameOfImg_)\((nimages + 1)).jpg"
    image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(imageName, ofType: nil))
    if image != nil {
        myArray.append(image)
    }
}
```

Comment: there is nothing like `addObject` method when you declare array as `var myArray = [UIImage]()`. It should be `append`

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari Thx, Fixed

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about to get all images in the main bundle which contain the `entity.attribute` string this is a 'native' translation.

```
let imagePaths = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathsForResourcesOfType("jpg", inDirectory:  nil)
let myArray = imagePaths.filter{ $0.containsString(entity.attribute) }.map { UIImage(contentsOfFile: $0) }
```